# cloze multichoice question in the latex using the package 'moodle'

Tags: equations, compilation-error, xml, moodle

I use both `Moodle` and `latex` to write all my quizzes. but, I use `latex` to generate formula rich questions in `moodle`. The latex package `Moodle` can do this. Then I import it as XML file to `moodle`. This works perfectly. Before import the quiz the latex compile the code and produce a PDF so can make sure everything ok. It works well for the close quiz question as well. But, when I have the all the question in the close quiz the 'multichoice' then when I import it as an xml then I get error message although latex compile it without any error. 
appreciate any help

**Latex code:**

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{moodle}
\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{MRTS}
\begin{cloze}{MRTS Q1}\\
A production function is given as $ Q=15\sqrt{KL}$. Q=quantity of output, L = the units of labour, K = the units of capital. The marginal product of labour, $MP_L$ of this function is:
\begin{multi}[horizontal]
\item*$7.5K^{0.5}L^{-0.5}$
\item $7.5K^{-0.5}L^{0.5}$
\item $K^{0.5}L^{-0.5}$
\item $K^{-0.5}L^{0.5}$
\item $15K^{0.5}L^{-0.5}$
\item $15K^{-0.5}L^{0.5}$
\end{multi}
A production function is given as $ Q=15\sqrt{KL}$. Q=quantity of output, L = the units of labour, K = the units of capital. The marginal product of labour, $MP_K$ of this function is:? 
\begin{multi}[horizontal]
\item $7.5K^{0.5}L^{-0.5}$
\item *$7.5K^{-0.5}L^{0.5}$
\item $K^{0.5}L^{-0.5}$
\item $K^{-0.5}L^{0.5}$
\item $15K^{0.5}L^{-0.5}$
\item $15K^{-0.5}L^{0.5}$
\end{multi}
A production function is given as $ Q=15\sqrt{KL}$. Q=quantity of output, L = the units of labour, K = the units of capital.The marginal rate of technical substitution associated with this production function is?\\ Note: $MRTS=\displaystyle -\frac{\frac{\partial Q}{\partial L}}{\frac{\partial Q}{\partial K}}$
\begin{multi}[horizontal]
\item $\frac{K}{L}$
\item*$-\frac{K}{L}$
\item  $\sqrt{\frac{K}{L}}$
\item  $\sqrt{\frac{L}{K}}$
\item $-\sqrt{\frac{K}{L}}$
\item $-\sqrt{\frac{L}{K}}$
\end{multi}
\end{cloze}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

[image: Moodle output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, add the preamble to your code to make it compilable. I have used moodle and cloze questions recently, so maybe I could help.

Comment: Just added. thanks

Comment: Hi Rmano, Thanks for your time and the replies. As in your first reply, I changed the XML file exponents to example k^0.5 \),and also tried k^\(0.5\) instead of ^{}, but none fo them didn't work and moodle still produces the same error message.  yes, your second reply, include the formula image is a good suggestion. thanks again for your contribution. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Rmano, Finally it worked when escape the { } with  \}. the XML file is accepted. Thank you so much.

Comment: yes, it is accepted but then the formula is mis-rendered --- ¿Can you share how you managed it? You can add an answer if you want.

Comment: Hi Rmano, I have attached the output but redact the questions. I was in the moodle discussion forum as well. As commented in the forum  I  escape the { } with \} in the answer then it worked. Thanks for your help. Regards,

Comment: Please see one of the answers: {1:MULTICHOICE_VS:=\(7.5K^{0.5\}L^{-0.5\}\)~\(7.5K^{-0.5\}L^{0.5\}\)~\(K^{0.5\}L^{-0.5\}\)~\(K^{-0.5\}L^{0.5\}\)~\(15K^{0.5\}L^{-0.5\}\)}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I suspect it is a bug/limitation of the Cloze type of questions. This MWE

```latex
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{moodle}

\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{Test cloze} 
\begin{cloze}{Multiple questions}

    A $x$ is

    \begin{multi}[vertical]
        One two three
        \item*  one $u^1$
        \item  two
        \item three
    \end{multi}
\end{cloze}

\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

works ok, and give the expected result in Moodle:

[image]

But if you add braces around the exponent:

```latex
\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{Test cloze} 
\begin{cloze}{Multiple questions}

    A $x$ is

    \begin{multi}[vertical]
        One two three
        \item*  one $u^{1}$
        \item  two
        \item three
    \end{multi}
\end{cloze}

\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

Moodle fails importing it with:

[image]

Now, the only difference between the two XML files generated is this one:

```
[romano:~/tmp] % diff quiz-hr-moodle\ \(copy\).xml quiz-hr-moodle.xml          
15c15
<     <text><![CDATA[<p></P><P>A \(x\) is </P><P>One two three {1:MULTICHOICE_V:=one \(u^{1}\)~two~three}</p>]]></text>
---
>     <text><![CDATA[<p></P><P>A \(x\) is </P><P>One two three {1:MULTICHOICE_V:=one \(u^1\)~two~three}</p>]]></text>
```

and so it seems that the parser of Moodle get confused by the closing brace in the formula. I really do not know how to escape it, and even if the problem is recognized in the Moodle doc, it seems that simply it will not work:

[image]

So basically my takeout is that you can't use formulas in answers in cloze questions. The manual says you can:

[image]

...but I didn't manage to get it going. Notice that if you go in the XML file and escape the `{` `}` with `\{`and `\}` then the XML file is accepted, but the formula is broken.

This does not happen in normal (no `cloze`) `multi` questions, fortunately.

So my stopgap solution would be to use Unicode formulas directly typed there, and switch to `lualatex` for the compilation.

Another stopgap solution is to use images for your formulas:

```
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{moodle}

\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{Test cloze} 
    \begin{cloze}{one cloze}
    A $x$ is

    \begin{multi}[vertical]
        One two three
    \item*  one \includegraphics[height=4ex]{formula1.png}
        \item  two
        \item three
    \end{multi}
\end{cloze}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

will render as:

[image: Output with embedded graph]

Not ideal (can be probably made better with a bit of transparency or whatever) but if you need it...

Answer (score 2):

I modified the moodle package to fix this bug. LaTeX equations can be used in cloze subquestion fields. See [this fixed issue](https://framagit.org/mattgk/moodle/issues/10).

Here is a MWE:

```latex
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{moodle} % development version 0.8
\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{Category}
\begin{cloze}{Question name}
Question text
\begin{multi}[vertical]
\item[feedback={$7.5K^{0.5}L^{-0.5}$ is correct}]*$7.5K^{0.5}L^{-0.5}$
\item[feedback={$7.5K^{-0.5}L^{0.5}$ is incorrect}] $7.5K^{-0.5}L^{0.5}$
\end{multi}
\end{cloze}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

the resulting PDF is rendered like this
[image: PDF obtained from MWE]

the resulting XML file is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This file was generated on 2020-11-10 by LuaLaTeX -->
<!-- running on Linux with the package moodle v0.8 -->

<quiz>
 
<question type="category">
  <category>
    <text>$course$/top/Category</text>
  </category>
</question>
 
<question type="cloze">
  <name format="html">
    <text><![CDATA[Question name]]></text>
  </name>
  <questiontext format="html">
    <text><![CDATA[<p>Question text {1:MULTICHOICE_VS:=\(7.5K^{0.5\}L^{-0.5\}\)#\(7.5K^{0.5\}L^{-0.5\}\) is correct~\(7.5K^{-0.5\}L^{0.5\}\)#\(7.5K^{-0.5\}L^{0.5\}\) is incorrect}</p>]]></text>
  </questiontext>
  <defaultgrade>1</defaultgrade>
  <generalfeedback format="html"><text/></generalfeedback>
  <penalty>0.10</penalty>
  <hidden>0</hidden>
</question>
 
</quiz>
```

and after import in Moodle (3.5 here with MathJax LaTeX renderer) the question preview looks like that
[image: Question preview after import of XML in Moodle]

Comment: Nice! What about contacting the original author and try to upload the changes on CTAN?

Comment: @Rmano I have been in contact with the original author but he no longer answers emails. I might start soon to go through the many steps required by the [LPPL](https://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt). In the meanwhile, feedback, contributions and testing are welcome.

Comment: You can try to ask in chat (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) --- several core team developers hang around there, and maybe somebody can help. For testing, maybe you should make available a "packed" (a `.tds` file would be the best) downloadable without registering...